# The difference between the onload event and the final HTTP response?

Tags: asp.net, performance, http, onload

I am working on optimizing the performance of my site and am confused by some of the timing issues.

Using Firebug and Page Speed I get a similar `onload` (Firebug) or `pageLoadTime` (Page Speed) readout. I am assuming this time is taken when the onload event fires.

I have also been using Fiddler to analyze the site, and the "Sequence duration" (The time from when the requests start until the responses complete) is always bigger than the "onload" and "pageLoadTime" times.

First, why are they different? Secondly, which one should I be more concerned about when trying to optimize my website? I am trying to minimize and speed up the HTTP requests.

Comment: I think that you have mix up the code behind run, the browser render time, the write to the browser time, and other thinks that are separated.

Comment: Could you explain? The onload event fires before the browser writes, correct? Shouldn't the HTTP responses be finished, or is my site still receiving responses at this time?

Comment: The onload on javascript ? The HTTP responses can flush what have up to a point, and then continue send data again flush etc... The code behind can run up to a point, flush or direct send return, or place them on a buffer and send them only when the buffer is ready all together...

Comment: Okay I am starting to understand, thanks. If I am testing for performance the time between the starting requests and the ending response is still a good metric though right?

Comment: I look the time that the user start see the first header, or the first  something and feels that the page is there and start rendering. See the amazon product pages, the menu on up appear in 400ms (more or less), and then continue to show the product. This first milliseconds that user see "something" is critical for make the user feel that the page is fast. Now to make your page fast there are many many tricks... and many levels of optimization that can make months of developing in big project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onload event fires after the browser has completed loading all of the content that was defined in the HTML including any iFrames and elements that Javascript appended to the page.

It isn't unusual for there to be javascript that executes in or after the onload handler that generates additional network activity (things like analytics beacons, slide shows, etc).  The browser will also usually request the favicon right after onload which may tickle fiddler's measurements as well.

As to what you should focus on, that is going to depend on your website and what is important for the user experience.  If you have an ecommerce-style site then you may care about the point in time when the above-the-fold results are visible and it may not track with the onload time at all.